# How do I make a transparent theme in Firefox Color?

Tags: firefox

I was thinking of making a transparent theme on Firefox, Are any ways to make a transparent theme in Firefox Color?

Comment: Have you asked the developer?

Comment: What developer?

Comment: The Firefox Color extension developer?

Comment: No, I didn't asked the developer.